# Convert blob file into webm with Whammy Lib

Tags: javascript, html5-video, video-recording, webm

I'm using Whammy Lib to generates a video with images.
After record the video, the Whammy lib returns a temp directory with a blob file.

```
blob:http%3A//localhost%3A8000/b07288dc-da33-409c-90bc-9d1ce949db35
```

I need to upload this file to my server with php, but I don't know how can I send a webm file instead the blob file.

To compile de video, I'm using:

```
videoEncoder = new Whammy.Video();
for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    videoCtx.putImageData(images[i].image, 0, 0);
    videoEncoder.add(videoCtx, images[i].duration);
}

blob = videoEncoder.compile();
file = (window.webkitURL || window.URL).createObjectURL(blob);
```

---

ANSWERED!

Update with the last code that I resolve my problem:

```
var data = $(form).serializeArray();
var formData = new FormData();
// blob is the return from Whammy Lib after compile
formData.append('webm', blob, 'video.webm');
```

I just have to append the blob file to a FormData and send to my php.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know Whammy Lib, but if you've got the blob object, then you can use the [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/FormData) object to send it as file to your server :

```
var f = new FormData();
f.append('videofile', b);
var xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST','savevideofile.php');
xhr.send(f);
```

Then in **savevideofile.php**

```
if($_FILES['videofile']){
    $my_file = $_FILES['videofile'];
    $my_blob = file_get_contents($my_file['tmp_name']);
    file_put_contents('your_file.webm', $my_blob);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the Blob object into array buffer and then send it to the server using WebSockets, for example.

```
blob = videoEncoder.compile();

var stream_ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost/webm");
stream_ws.binaryType = 'arraybuffer';

var fileReader = new FileReader();
var arrayBuffer;
fileReader.onload = function() {
     arrayBuffer = this.result;
     stream_ws.send(arrayBuffer);
}
fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(blob);
```

The websocket listening process then can receive the webm file as binaries and save it to disk.